# OpenCL: parrallel write from host to device buffer?

Tags: c++, buffer, opencl

I have a cl_mem buffer that's quite large (100 million floats). I'm trying to decrease the amount of time it takes to fill it with data from the host (I have to pass data from host to device many times, and currently I re-initialize the buffer each time).

Instead of initializing with clCreateBuffer/CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR over and over, it seems it would be more efficient to initialize the buffer once, and then update its data with a multi-threaded approach each subsequent time (so multiple CPU threads each update subsets of the data simultaneously).

Is such an approach possible? I've looked into clEnqueueWriteBuffer, and while it allows a subset of a buffer to be updated, it seems like multiple calls to it would still be executed sequentially by the command queue. Do I need multiple command queues? Is this approach even possible?

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear from your question whether your initialisation/update would be the same every time, or whether the whole of the buffer needs updating between runs. Obviously the easiest way to speed things up will be to remove any duplication of effort and don't copy the same data multiple times.

Do your measurements suggest that you are *not* limited by the interface between your CPU and device? Because if you need to copy N MB every time, your device is connected to CPU/system memory by a B MB/s interface, and your copying time is not wildly more than N/B seconds, no amount of multithreading is going to help you.

If you are limited by the sequential nature of some CPU calculation and the subsequent copy to the the buffer, you could use the asynchronous variant of `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()` to start copying the first chunk of data while calculating the next, etc. Note that `clEnqueueWriteBuffer()`/`CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR` typically makes use of the device's DMA engines, which typically doesn't require much intervention from the host CPUs, and so can run entirely in parallel with calculations. (Host memory bandwidth is of course shared as always.)

If that is too cumbersome for your purposes, it may be useful to use [clEnqueueMapBuffer](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueMapBuffer.html) to map the buffer into the host application's address space. This allows any number of threads to access arbitrary areas of it simultaneously. Be aware, however, that this is no silver bullet, and unless your OpenCL implementation explicitly specifies how this is implemented in practice, it can be that you actually make things worse with it because it might end up copying *more* than previously.

If your device kernels don't actually end up reading all of the buffer (and you just don't know in advance which parts it will need), or possibly if they only read all of it precisely once, in a nice and predictable pattern, but your host code needs to read & write lots or write to random locations, you could try buffers created with `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR`. This isn't zero-copy in all implementations, but the idea is to give the device direct access to host memory. You're again limited by the device uplink interface bandwidth, and latency is typically much worse than to device memory, but if your device doesn't actually need to read all of it, this could be faster as you don't have to push the whole buffer down the pipe.

Finally, if your CPUs are somehow preprocessing/unpacking the data, you could try offloading that to the device instead.

Comment: The data is different with each iteration, so I can't simply forego the constant updates. I'm not exactly sure how to calculate theoretical speed limits for transferring to a device, but it's a PCI-E 3.0 connection to a NVidia 1080ti GPU...so I was just assuming I'd be able to squeeze a bit more juice out of it since it's fairly beefy, but you could be right that I'm already at the limit. I will experiment more with successive async copies during calculations (your 3rd paragraph)...but overall was moreso wondering if I can do multiple copies simultaneously to transfer the data in parallel...

Comment: @Tyson If you're using the full 16 lanes of PCIe 3.0, your theoretical limit is a little below 16GB/s. On consumer or small workstation systems with more than one PCIe x16 slot, you typically only get 8 lanes if 2 slots are taken, which halves the maximum bandwidth.

Comment: So would you see a benefit in further pursuing the optimization I'm trying to achieve (parallel transfer)? Or in your opinion is a synchronous clCreateBuffer call on a float vector about as fast as things can get (ignoring optimizations like progressive calls to clEqueueWriteBuffer as the data is calculated). In other words, if you were given a 100mil float array and had to get it onto the GPU once, would you consider a single call to clCreateBuffer to be the absolute fastest way, regardless of how many CPU cores you were working with?

Comment: I'd probably try both: (1) the async variant of `clEqueueWriteBuffer()`, trying to hide the upload time by doing other things on the CPU in the mean time; (2) allocate the memory (a) with or (b) without `CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR`, map the memory using `clEnqueueMapBuffer()` and directly use that as the destination array for whatever is generating/loading the 100 million floats on the CPU. Don't forget to unmap before using the buffer with a kernel. Version (2) will almost certainly beat anything else on integrated GPUs with unified memory (test for `CL_DEVICE_HOST_UNIFIED_MEMORY`).

Comment: Your 1080Ti doesn't have UMA, so to a large extent what works best will depend on everything else: memory access patterns, where the 100M floats are coming from (does generating/loading them take an amount of time comparable to or greater than the VRAM upload?)